# Placing two strings in center of page for Python on the same line

Tags: python, string, centering

I wanted to place the two strings, "Your name is " and name variable in the center of the page but I tried using `.center(165)` and `rjust(165//2)` commands but does not seem to work.
My code:

```
name=input("your name :".rjust(165//2))
print("your name is " + name).rjust(165//2)
```

which does not work

what my desired outcome:

```
                                      Your name: example
                                     Your name is example
```

Comment: Can you add what your example code does to show how it differs from your desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name=input("your name :".rjust(165//2))
print(f"your name is {name}".rjust(165//2))
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation about how this addresses the problem.